# PHP - как правильно использовать класс?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Класс class.send_mail_func.php

```
class phpmailer {

        public function sendMail($message, $subject){

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once  ('./PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php');
require_once  ('./PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once  ('./PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');

  //отправляем почту
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
  $mail->setLanguage('ru', './PHPMailer/language/');
  $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
  $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->Host = 'host';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = 'mail@mailru';                 // SMTP username
  $mail->Password = '123';                           // SMTP password
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
  $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

  $mail->setFrom('m@m.ru', 'Text');
  $mail->addAddress('user@user.ru', 'User');     // Add a recipient
  $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->msgHTML($message);

  if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Message could not be sent.';
      echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
      echo 'Message has been sent';
  }

}
}
```

Использую так

```
  include './class.send_mail_func.php';
 $email_send = new phpmailer();
 $email_send->sendMail($message,$subject);
```

Получаю ошибку:﻿ Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /home/class.send_mail_func.php on line 7

Как правильно использовать use внутри класса?

Comment: С какой целью вы пытаетесь обернуть в класс методы PHPMailer-а? Даже если пока не смотреть на реализацию, а просто попытаться понять - для чего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это пакет PHPMailer, который Вы взяли на packagist или github-e, то, на том же гитхабе есть прекрасный пример. Я так понял, что Вы пытаетесь обернуть этот клас внутрь своего?

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//т.к. автолоад не настроен подключаете напрямую классы
require_once  ('./PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php');
require_once  ('./PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require_once  ('./PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');


class MyMail {
 public function sendMail($message,$subject) {
//ваш код тут 
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
//etc ...
    }
    }
```

вызов у Вас правильный

```
include './class.send_mail_func.php';
 $email_send = new MyMail();
 $email_send->sendMail($message,$subject);
```

Comment: PHPMailer\PHPMailer, PHPMailer\Exception не трейты.

Comment: Ввело в заблуждение использование этих классов внутри class phpmailer - предпололжил что это трейты.

Comment: Да запустилось, все верно. require_once - после use надо .